# How to evaluate these derivatives

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, differentials

I'm trying to evaluate the following functions S1,S2 and their derivatives:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see the S1 and it's derivatives it's working but for the S2 and it's derivatives I'm getting the error displayed above:

```
Part::partd: Part specification ec1[[2]] is longer than depth of object.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to work with substitution rules rather than equations.  When we already have lists of equations like these

```
eqns = {R'[t] == -V Cos[ψ[t] - ϵ[t]],
   ϵ'[t] == -V Sin[ψ[t] - ϵ[t]]/R[t],
   ψ'[t] == u[t]};

f = {s1[t] == R[t] Cos[ϵ[t]] - CC*t,
   s2[t] == R[t] Sin[ϵ[t]] - m*t};
```

`ToRules` can convert the equations to rules like this

```
rules = ToRules /@ eqns // Flatten
g = ToRules /@ f // Flatten

(*  {Derivative[1][R][t] -> -V Cos[ϵ[t] - ψ[t]], 
     Derivative[1][ϵ][t] -> (V Sin[ϵ[t] - ψ[t]])/R[t], 
     Derivative[1][ψ][t] -> u[t]}  

    {s1[t] -> -CC t + Cos[ϵ[t]] R[t], 
     s2[t] -> -m t + R[t] Sin[ϵ[t]]}  *)
```

Now we can take the derivatives of the rules like this

```
dg = D[g, t] /. rules // Simplify
ddg = D[dg, t] /. rules // Simplify

(*   {Derivative[1][s1][t] -> -CC - V Cos[ψ[t]], 
      Derivative[1][s2][t] -> -m - V Sin[ψ[t]]}
   {(s1^′′)[t] -> V Sin[ψ[t]] u[t],
    (s2^′′)[t] -> -V Cos[ψ[t]] u[t]}   *)
```

Now, if we need lists of equations instead of rules, we can convert back to equations like this

```
{df, ddf} = {dg, ddg} /. Rule -> Equal

(*   {{Derivative[1][s1][t] == -CC - V Cos[ψ[t]], 
       Derivative[1][s2][t] == -m - V Sin[ψ[t]]}, 
     {(s1^′′)[t] == V Sin[ψ[t]] u[t], 
      (s2^′′)[t] == -V Cos[ψ[t]] u[t]}}   *)
```

Another way to obtain these results is to take the derivative of the `f` equations and then `ReplaceAll` with `rules`.  If we than apply `Simplify`, however, `Simplify` may move all the terms to the lefthand side or to the righthand side, or vice versa, which may be undesirable.  `Simplify` could be applied to only the righthand side, if desired.